# Can use sparql for RDFa

Tags: rdf, sparql, rdfa

is there possibility to query content on my own site? I´ve read your comments and I know that this does not have a big sense but I only would like to simulate this proces between 2 sites and lear myself how it really works.. I want to query content form one site to another with sparql endpint but I dont know if this is possible. If you query data from dbpedia so data are structured in rdf. But on my ow site if I use rdf mappings for fields it is RDFa.. or? thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use an online SPARQL processor, such as the one at http://sparql.org/sparql.html.

Just add the URL of your RDFa page to the FROM field, and you can query it. The response won't be as quick as if you're using a local RDF library, but it's useful for testing.

You could also use the command line tool roqet, from the rasqal library:

```
$ roqet --exec 'SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }' --data 'http://steve.harris.name/cv/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've understood your question, but...

RDFa is a way to embed RDF (meta)data into web pages. In order to query that data, you need to extract and load it into an RDF triple store that supports SPARQL queries (most triple stores do this).

If you want to query the data remotely then you need an RDF library that serves up the SPARQL endpoint via HTTP, rather than purely as a local API.

Does that help?